Siri stumbling over certain words with HomePod?
I have two HomePods in two different rooms in my house - call them "Living Room" and "Studio".  HomePod Mini in the studio, HomePod in the living room.   For what it's worth, I also have an AppleTV in the living room connected to a monitor - it uses the HomePod for audio.
Lately Siri has started to occasionally stumble over the first word or two it says when it starts to speak.  This only occurs with certain words -- so today, for instance, today I asked about the weather and it started to say "Should be...", the "should" was somehow digitally distorted.  With other questions about the weather, to which it answers "Expect...", or "Today...", there's no problem.  I've only noticed this with the HomePod, not the HomePod mini, although I haven't tested it extensively.  In fact it happens so rarely and randomly I'm not sure how to test it.  Music played through the HomePod seems fine.  It's as if it were encountering some initial buffering problem when starting out with certain words.
Has anyone experienced or heard of this?  Anything to do?
For what it's worth, the HomePod is almost brand new (the Mini is about six months old).  The only other thing of note seems to be that Siri doesn't respond as readily on the HomePod as the HomePod mini, but I've been assuming that since the HomePod is generally louder, perhaps it simply doesn't hear me over it's own sound.
